# Do I sacrifice disk space if i make my column definition for NUMERIC too broad?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have a table that I expect to have hundreds of millions, if not billions, of rows.

three of the columns are of data type `NUMERIC(16,12)`, which accurately represents the data that was put in there.

Recently, people tried to put in numbers that were one integer too large in front of the decimal (i.e 12345.6789101112), which didn't fit in the column, so I am going to expand it.

Business relations aside (I should have known that change was coming, right?) I would like to sort of future-proof this table.  Am I sacrificing a lot in terms of disk space if I make this huge table, say, `NUMERIC(20,12)` instead of only bumping it up to `NUMERIC(17,12)`, which is all i would need to do to fix the current problem at hand?

Comment: I often wish I could set "max decimal places" rather than a precision/scale; i.e. arbitrary precision, with scale determined on a value by value basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL):

`Numeric values are physically stored without any extra leading or trailing zeroes. Thus, the declared precision and scale of a column are maximums, not fixed allocations.`

So, I think you are not sacrificing disk space if you go for a bigger precision.